# Intent for getting multiple images

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

Is there an intent requesting to get multiple images?

We are aware of `Intent.ACTION_PICK` or `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for getting a single image. Also our app registers as IntentFilter for `android.intent.action.SEND` and `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE`

However, we would like our app to make use of Gallery like applications to pick multiple images. Is there an intent for that?

Comment: Since I couldn't find anything and no one answered, I assume the answer is no.

Comment: Try https://github.com/learnNcode/MediaChooser library .. hope it helps

Comment: Is there still no real answer to this?

Answer (score 27):

I also wanted Intent for picking multiple images in android but I failed.I came across custom gallery with custom theme.

Look at here [MultipleImagePick](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick) to pick single image and to pick multiple image and also you can change theme according to your app.

[image][image][image]

**Updated**

Thanks @[sunshine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136023/sunshine) for guiding me to limit maximum images selection.

```
in CustomGalleryActivity.java 

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemMulClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
            if (adapter.getSelected().size() >= MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "maximum items selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                adapter.changeSelection(v, position);
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: can i put maximum limit of images that user can select like this library provides https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser

Comment: yes you can set limit in onItemClick of gridview. Pass integer extra frompickbutton and according to that set limit in onItemClick.

Comment: Awesome library! Is there any way to change the directories that Luminous looks in for images? Or could you point me to the code where this directory is set? On one of the devices I am testing with, Luminous does not see pictures in the Pictures directory, while on other devices, I see pictures from both the Pictures dir and the Camera dir. Any guidance?

Comment: what is the dependency for this library. where i can find this library

Answer (score 18):

You need to add this to your manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I found this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5dfcb951d5aa7e4b) to be extremely helpful, it explains how to also retrieve the images.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more and mentioned exact code? It would be easy for others to implement the same. Because many are defining their own gallery using custom gridview or listview and selecting photos from there.

Comment: that is for sending images; the question is for getting images; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585815/select-multiple-images-from-android-gallery