# Gallery Intent to Camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have an app that on ImageButton click it opens the Gallery intent from where you can either choose some pictures OR take another one using the Camera intent.

My question is: I have made a camera layout that I would like to use instead of the one from the gallery intent. How could I use my custom layout instead of the basic one? Thanks

Comment: Try to create your custom Gallery Activity instead of default and use your custom gallery layout there.

Comment: Could you provide some code for that? :) cheers

Comment: Check my ans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426113/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-android/23426985#23426985

Comment: Ok, my question might have been misunderstood @HareshChhelana

I'm not planning on changing the gallery intent. When you open the gallery using the intent, in the top right corner, you have a camera button which will take you to the camera app BUT I would like instead of using the camera intent there, use my camera layout.

Comment: i think which not possible for your custom camera view.

Comment: I am not sure about it as well :) but would like to get more answers. Thanks though!

Comment: create a chooser, in which you pass the intent to open your camera activity and the intent to open the gallery.

Comment: I'd appreciate some code :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I  understand, you need Intent.ACTION_PICK

See details here: http://sudhanshuvinodgupta.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-intentactionpick.html