# Android Select Multiple Images from gallery?

Tags: android, image, select

How can I select multiple images from gallery by using java.
I have Use this code but no error occurs 
and can not able to select image from gallery. 
Here is my code:

**mainactivity.java**

```
 //button On Click:
{

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE); 

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
                     //super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    switch(requestCode) { 
                        case 1234:
                            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                                cursor.moveToFirst();

                                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                                cursor.close();


                                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                                /* Now you have choosen image in Bitmap format in object "yourSelectedImage". You can use it in way you want! */
                            }
                        }
            }

            });
```

**It's not working. I can't select image.**

Comment: here is the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/23426985/3983054

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426113/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-android

Answer (score 0):

@Drashti Kapadia :You can use Android open source library [MultipleImagePick](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick). And it uses [Universal image loader library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for asynchronous loading and caching.

### Features and Benefits:

1. Select multiple images - Option to select multiple images from
   Gallery and fast scroll over the Gallery
2. Maximum selection limit - Option to set maximum image selection
   limit
3. Custom button title and error message - There is a option to
   customize button title and error message
4. Method for scale down the bitmap - To avoid out of memory issue,
   this module has in build bitmap scale down method
5. Callback methods - Success, error and cancel callback methods

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Hope this helps!

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); // allow the user to select multiple items, only available in Android API 18 and higher.
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```