# how to open gallery to select multiple image?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I want to open gallery with multiple image selection functionality and i am using following code.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

It opens gallery app but doesn't let me choose multiple images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select multiple images from gallery in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426113/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-android)

Comment: the `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` option is only available in Android **API 18 and higher**.

Comment: i am running the following code in kitkat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select multiple images from android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585815/select-multiple-images-from-android-gallery)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me from api22 to api29.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 105);
```

then in activity result overmethod add this code.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 105) {
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Uri imageUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    // your code for multiple image selection
                }
            } else {
              Uri uri = data.getData();
                // your codefor single image selection
            }
```

Note: after you got the gallery screen hold the image little longer. then in top right click "open". it will allow you to select multiple images.

Comment: What is `HoiviaAppPermision` ?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish i updated my answer for your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

To select multiple images I use this :

1. Declare a variable

   > ActivityResultLauncher activityResultLauncher;

2.Call Register Method in OnCreate Method

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload_ad_images);
    RegisterOpenImageDialog();
 }
```

3.this is the register method

```
private void RegisterOpenImageDialog() {
        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents(), new ActivityResultCallback<List<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> result) {
                if (result != null) {

                    int x = result.size();
                    
                    //Do What you Want Here ................
                    
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

4.when the user click select image button

```
private void btnSelectImage() {
     activityResultLauncher.launch("image/*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click and hold to select multiple image. Don't just click on image. Also you can receive those image using this.

```
int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;
String imageEncoded;
List<String> imagesEncodedList;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(data.getData()!=null){

                Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

            }else {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        mArrayUri.add(uri);
                        // Get the cursor
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        // Move to first row
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                        cursor.close();

                    }
                    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: i am doing in same way click and hold the images in my Samsung Note 2 but it doesn't working for me

Comment: I tried to my Xperia z. It's working perfectly. May be it's about the gallery application's problem.