# Pick multiple images from gallery

Tags: android, uri, gallery, image-gallery

How to read/retrieve paths or `Uri[]` when I select multiple images from gallery?

I want to call this:

```
Uri[] originalUri = data.getData();
```

But in reality I'm getting this  only, fetching only one `Uri`:

```
 Uri originalUri = data.getData();
```

Comment: How about saving the uri first in a ArrayList? then do a for-each loop?

Comment: @JLONG My problem is I am unable to get that array. Please read my question carefully. It rest rives only one Uri though I selected multiple images

Comment: Sorry bout that, anyway have you looked at this link? http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery.html

Comment: I have already gone through it, but I don't want to fetch all the gallery in my app.

Comment: @RIT For multiples image selection you have create your own activity to load all image and implement multiple selection in it.

Comment: @Herry I just said it above, I don't want to load all the images in my app. I just want to fetch selected only.

Comment: @RIT but in android they are not giving any intent that use for multiples image selection ,So let me known which code you are using to start multiples image selection.

Comment: It started from Kitkat version. But unable to get it that's why I put the question over here.

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33228269/3649347

Answer (score 12):

@RIT as said by you that you want to get multiples images in andorid kitkat .

I have try below code which work for me for Xperia M2 4.4.4

For start image selection activity

```
private void startImageSelection(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGES);
    }
```

But user need to select images by long press

Now to read selected images Uri use below code for onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGES){

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                //data.getParcelableArrayExtra(name);
                //If Single image selected then it will fetch from Gallery
                if(data.getData()!=null){

                    Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                }else{
                    if(data.getClipData()!=null){
                        ClipData mClipData=data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri=new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for(int i=0;i<mClipData.getItemCount();i++){

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);

                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images"+ mArrayUri.size());
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Let me give a try, will get back to you asap. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: finally something that works (w/ selecting from g+ photo app via chooser)

Comment: @VVB: can this answer on your old question be accepted? It looks like you were intending to reply to Herry again, and did not. Is the question abandoned?

Comment: I didn't get time to hands on.

Comment: does clipdata return data in the same order it is selected ?

Answer (score 0):

for selecting multiple images from gallery you can use the following code

```
String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
};

mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        null,
        null,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " DESC"
);

columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
```

Comment: I think you have not understood my question. Anyways thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int cols = cursor.getColumnCount();
            String columns = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                columns += cursor.getColumnName(j) + " | ";
            }

            imagePathUriList.add(cursor.getString(1));


        }
```

Comment: I think you have not understood my question. Anyways thanks for reply

Comment: ok means user will manually select images from gallery right?

Comment: Exactly, please see the comments for more details

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585815/select-multiple-images-from-android-gallery

Comment: Thanks. But I have already gone through these also check my above comments.

Comment: I think you have to crate custom gallery or else use this https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66451/discussion-between-rit-and-techhelper).

Answer (score 0):

here's my take of it in Kotlin. This call is from a fragment, and should work in an activity with little to no tweaking.

```
//const lives in companion or above class definition
private const val PHOTO_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE = 36

private fun launchPhotoPicker() {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).apply {
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
        type = "image/*"
    }.let {
        startActivityForResult(it, PHOTO_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            val selectedPhotoUris = mutableListOf<Uri>()

            data?.data?.let {
                selectedPhotoUris.add(it)
            }

            data?.clipData?.let { clipData ->
                for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
                    clipData.getItemAt(i).uri.let { uri ->
                        selectedPhotoUris.add(uri)
                    }
                }
            }

            //data.data is usually the first item in clipdata
            //I prefer to not make assumptions and just squash dupes
            //I don't trust like that
            val uris = selectedPhotoUris.distinctBy { it.toString() }

            handlePhotoUris(uris)
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}

private fun handlePhotoUris(uris: List<Uri>) {
    Log.d("photoPicking", "handle uris size: ${it.size}")
    //do stuff here
}
```