# Android Java: Extract substring from uri string after particular characters

Tags: java, android, string, substring, extract

I would like to extract a substring starting from particular substring.

I'm getting an array of URIs of multiple images from Photo Library via this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376429/1371949). But the URIs are something like this

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38
```

I would like to remove *content://* and get only

```
com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38
```

I've searched through the Internet but found no best solution. Perhaps to avoid regex because it's kinda heavy.

At the moment I choose not to get the substring by checking after second '/' because it feels kinda "hardcoded".

Not sure if I've missed a good solution but please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get whatever string comes after a certain substring, in this case "content://", you could use the split method.

```
String string = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38";
String uri = string.split("content://")[1];
```

Or you could use the substring and indexOf methods like in the other answer, but add on the length of the substring.

```
String string = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38";
String sub = "content://";
String uri = string.substring(string.indexOf(sub) + sub.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `substring` method in order to create new strings without content://, something like this :

```
String string = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38"
String secondString = string.substring(string.indexOf("com.android"));
```