# Android picks multiple images from gallery limit

Tags: android, image, gallery

Hi guys there is a way to set a limit on picking multiple items from gallery, without a custom gallery?

Like putting an extra field to intent or something.

Thanks

Comment: Checked already ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19848052/1944896

Comment: yes I checked. One guy asked for a solution but none reply. @TheLittleNaruto