# Setting the maximum number of items to be returned by an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-image

I have an intent that can be used to allow the user to select some images in an image app like galley(or any other present in the user's device).

I want the user to select **ONLY 10 images** but i don't know how i can set this maximum on the intent. **i have tried to see if i can use ClipData but clipdata doesn't have methods to set maximum number of items.**

```
ClipboardManager manager = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)
ClipData clipdata = manager.getPrimaryClip();// in short whether i get 
or i create a clipdata, there are no methods to set maximum number of
items to be held into that clip
```

here is my intent.

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

**How can i limit the user to select only 10 photos?**

Comment: Did you get any solution for limit selection?

Comment: @Nikhil Yes. see my answer below. I had forgot to post the solution. kudos for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good image and videos selection library called Matisse. You call specify the total number of images or videos that you want a user to select. Selection happens without leaving your app since an activity called `MatisseActivity` presents all images from the user phone where the user will select the ones he wants until the specified maximum number is reached.

https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse

```
Matisse.from(MainActivity.this)
        .choose(MimeType.allOf())
        .countable(true)
        .maxSelectable(10)
        .thumbnailScale(0.85f)
        .imageEngine(new GlideEngine())
        .forResult(REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE);
```

Answer (score 5):

using `ClipData` check returned item count

```
ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
// here you can check how many images user has selected.
if(mClipData.getItemCount() >= 10) {
    // do needful here
    Log.e("APP_TAG", "Greater than THRESHOLD.");
    // show some error
    return;
}
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585815/select-multiple-images-from-android-gallery) question for more details.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this library :
https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2785

It allows you to set maximum number of images that can be shared. You can also customize PickerActivity by setting color of actionBar & statusBar. Also can set Your custom message when reached to specified limit.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: mmmm i think it's an awesome library

Comment: @EdijaeCrusar Agreed!