# Select multiple images from android gallery and get it path

Tags: java, android, select, path, gallery

I know that there is a lot of examples on the internet for it but no one of those does what I really want. I want to select multiple images with an intent and get it "url" like this code does with one. (I know that this code cannot select more than one, but I use this as example of what I'm trying to do)

Code:

```
public static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 0;
public void LoadImg() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

ArrayList<Part> files = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            files.add(new FilePart("uploadedfile[" + String.valueOf(files.size()) + "]", new File(picturePath)));
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Searching on the internet I found this example from Laith Mihyar in this post: [Select multiple images from android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585815/select-multiple-images-from-android-gallery)
and I want to do the same here, but the file path is different here and dont work for what I'm trying to do.

Code:

```
int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1
 String imageEncoded;    
 List<String> imagesEncodedList;
Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(data.getData()!=null){

                    Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                }else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);
                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                            cursor.close();

                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why doesnt it work? And what are you trying to do? Pretty vague all. And what is the problem when a file path is different? Unclear.

Comment: I need to get the path to a file, but when I try with the second one I get an app name (like com.appname.x) and a file with an id instead of a path that is what I'm trying to get. I try to get something like: "/content/files/image.png" and I get "com.company.appname/&file6647" or something like that

Comment: For what do you need a path to a file? Use the uri! You can do everything with it. What do you want to do?

Comment: The Uri return the rare url with the getPath() and I'm trying to upload those files with the Ion lib, that needs a path

Comment: You better look for a small function that uploads file by uri. (30. lines?). Or use a library that manages uries.

Comment: The problem is that the url that this code return is not valid(not at least using the uri) cause I can't even load it in an ImageView.

Comment: The url ? I thought we were taking about uries. What do you mean? Show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "file path". `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not have to return a `file` `Uri`, and most of the time on newer devices it will return a `content` `Uri`.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Use `DocumentFile` and `fromSingleUri()` to get at metadata about the content identified by the `Uri`.

> I can't even load it in an ImageView

Picasso and other image-loading libraries (even Ion) work with `content` `Uri` values without an issue.

> I'm trying to upload those files with the Ion lib, that needs a path

The best solution would be to use a better HTTP client library, one that offers greater flexibility. OkHttp (with Okio) should be able to handle uploading from a `Uri`.

Or, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content. Use `FileOutputStream` to get a stream on some local file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Use Java I/O to copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`. Then, use the local file with Ion.

Comment: Could you help me with an example for loading the file with Ion pls? I'm not very acquainted with this and I really need to use Ion.