# Select multiple images from gallery and show in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have to select multiple images from gallery and display them into horizontal recycler view, but I'm confusing how to do it right. I've created a recyclerview adapter for it

```
public class HorizontalRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRecyclerView.HorizontalViewHolder> {

    private int[] images;
    private Uri uri;

    public HorizontalRecyclerView(int[] images, Uri uri) {
        this.images = images;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image, parent, false);
        return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HorizontalViewHolder horizontalViewHolder, int position) {
        //horizontalViewHolder.mImageRecyclerView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        horizontalViewHolder.mImageRecyclerView.setImageURI(uri);

        Picasso.get()
                .load(images[position])
                .into(horizontalViewHolder.mImageRecyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mImageRecyclerView;

        public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgLoader);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain how can I do right?

Comment: show your Activity Code

Comment: `images` is integer array? Are you sure you passing correct image path reference?

Comment: I want to know how do this in my activity

Comment: You can check this [example](https://demonuts.com/select-multiple-images-gallery/)

Comment: check https://demonuts.com/select-multiple-images-gallery/

Comment: Yeah, but how can attach images to recyclerview

Comment: What does `images` contain ? When you pass an `int` to `Picasso.get().load(..)` that `int` has to be the ID of a drawable (something like `R.drawable.image_name`).

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete Yes I did this

Comment: Please add relevant code along with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like,

Define your recyclerView and adapter like this,

```
ArrayList<Uri> uri = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
HorizontalRecyclerView adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    adapter = new HorizontalRecyclerView(uri);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Step 1: Select multiple images from Gallery (can be inside an onClick)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pictures: "), 1);
```

Step 2: Once selected you need to extract the selected image's URI and store it in an `ArrayList<Uri>`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    uri.add(data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } else if (data.getData() != null) {
            String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: Make changes to your Adapter like this

```
public class HorizontalRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRecyclerView.HorizontalViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Uri> uri;

    public HorizontalRecyclerView(ArrayList<Uri> uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HorizontalViewHolder horizontalViewHolder, int position) {
        horizontalViewHolder.mImageRecyclerView.setImageURI(uri.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return uri.size();
    }

    public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mImageRecyclerView;

        public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the trick. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023265/6845131).

Comment: my adapter is null, I think the adapter is the problem I'm not doing right

Comment: Are you initializing your adapter properly?

Comment: yeah, I initialized

Comment: Can you please edit your question and display the adapter code and the activity code.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5309190/9640177) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19585815/9640177)

```
// before onCreate declare ---
final int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;

// in onclick listener
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
```

Then you should also override onActivityResult

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     try {
>         // When an Image is picked
>         if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
>                 && null != data) {
>             // Get the Image from data
>
>             String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
>         imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
>         if(data.getData()!=null){
>
>                 Uri mImageUri=data.getData();
>
>                 // Get the cursor
>                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
>                         filePathColumn, null, null, null);
>                 // Move to first row
>                 cursor.moveToFirst();
>
>                 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
>                 imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
>                 cursor.close();
>
>             } else {
>                 if (data.getClipData() != null) {
>                 ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
>                 ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
>                 for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
>
>                         ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
>                     Uri uri = item.getUri();
>                     mArrayUri.add(uri);
>                     // Get the cursor
>                     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
>                     // Move to first row
>                     cursor.moveToFirst();
>
>                         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
>                     imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
>                     imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
>                     cursor.close();
>
>                     }
>                     Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
>             }
>         }
>     } else {
>         Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
>                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     }
> } catch (Exception e) {
>     Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
>                 .show();
> }
>
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> }
> ```

Quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34047251/9640177

Comment: Yes I did this like the example

Comment: Did you succeed??? Similar code worked for me but too lazy to open old projects

Comment: No, I can select multiple images on gallery but I cannot show in RecyclerView. After seleccting them, I have to send to server. I already did this