# Uploading several images

Tags: android, image, gallery, onactivityresult

I am trying to upload several pictures from my emulator, and this section of code works fine ( I can select couple pictures at the same time ) -

```
   private void OpenGallery() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
}
```

BUT, I can not understand how to implement the onActivityResult function.
the data is correct but when I am trying to to data.getData() my emulator is shutting down. My onActivityResult function looks like this -

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Log.d("TAG","DATA  " + data); // I get data with 3 images for example
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData(); // NOT WORKING
                final InputStream imageStream = 
                  getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. If data.getData() is null you should examine data.getClipData(); which can contain more uries than one. Your code should handle both data types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023265/11647620