# How to select multiple image/video in android project?

Tags: android, android-intent, static-libraries, photo-gallery

I am creating app in which I want to choose multiple photo and video from photo/video library of device, to upload.

But using native sdk picker we can choose one by one.

Is there any library by which we can make pickerview multiple selection by putting checkbox or something.

Please help

Comment: why u should not use your own list just fetch all data and show in list  and give multiple selection

Comment: Can you give me some code for the same.... Actually i am not a Android developer.... I am a iPhone developer and this is my first project so I am having issue with it

Comment: if i will give u code for getting all data then could u save that in wrapper and show that data dude

Comment: Okay please do... I will try

Comment: @See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15029515/185022

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select multiple images from Photo Gallery on Android using Intents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official picker yet which supports all versions of Android.

**Official Image picker:**

See ALLOW_MULTIPLE option (API Level >=18)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT

**Third party libraries:**
See this question:

[select multiple images in Android Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379579/select-multiple-images-in-android-gallery/12806036#12806036)